# Chrome - HTTPS sites unaccessible

Tags: google-chrome

Recently on Chrome I started being unable to access any HTTPS sites. If I try, I get a page like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u74f6.png) and cannot get though to the site. This works with other computers with Chrome, and different browsers on this same computer. Any ideas how to fix this?

Edit: Using Mac OS

Comment: Go to `https://accounts.google.com/` on Chrome, right-click on the page and select "View page info". Go to "Connections" tab on the pop-up and hit certificate information. It should say:
>Issued to: accounts.google.com  
Issued by: Google Internet Authority G2  
Valid from 7/ 30/ 2014 to 10/ 27/ 2014

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can ever think of that my machines have trouble accessing HTTPS sites is if the clock is wrong. You haven't listed the operating system you're using, but both Windows and  OS X have a 'time sync' functionality; try syncing your clock up to `time.apple.com` or `time.microsoft.com` and seeing if this ameliorates your issue.

Comment: Thats already synced :/